# Sql Server Browser service running but still server name not showing in VS2015

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ado.net

I'm using sql server 2016 and VS2015

I tried these steps:

```
Open the Run dialog (WinKey + R)
Type: "services.msc"
Select SQL Server Browser
Click Properties
Change "disabled" to either "Manual" or "Automatic"
When the "Start" service button gets enable, click on it.
```

But after that I'm still unable to see local server name in my visual studio
[attached the screenshot after running the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Stg.png)

[Image while accessing in through MVC application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBGLv.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: SQL Server Browser is not the main SQL Server service. It should be called something like `SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER)` or labeled by instance. I'm fairly sure the former is not required to make a connection to VS, as it's disabled on my system and I can connect.

Comment: MSQLSERVER service is running but still unable to see the server name

Comment: Are you able to connect with SSMS?

Comment: Yes I'm able to connect to ssms